# I cant deserialize xml file, there is always something wrong

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

So on my winrt app im trying to load a class from a xml file on one of my application folders and im having a problem where no matter what i do there will be always something wrong, or either i have a `missing file exception` or i have a `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` Below is how im trying to load the class:
path = "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><cards></cards>`"

```
    Dim instance As T
    Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path.ToString())
    Dim Stream As New MemoryStream(b)

    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(Type)
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream)
    instance = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), T)
    Return instance
```

on the line `instance = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), T)` i get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.. Ok so lets pass the file path instead, in this case path = "`ms-appx:///Data/cardsDB.xml`"

```
    Using reader2 As TextReader = New StringReader(path)
        Dim xml2 As New XmlSerializer(Type)
        instance = DirectCast(xml2.Deserialize(reader2), T)
    End Using
    Return instance
```

On the same line, `instance = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), T)`, in this case i get `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` and thats actually true because if i debug that line and i open `reader2` options i can see a `_s = "ms-appx:///Data/cardsDB.xml"`.. Now im really lost in here, if i pass a path i can't see the xml and when i pass the xml i can't find the file.. Can someone explain me how to do this :(

Also on a side note when im programming in vb with wpf a streamreader can get a string as a parameter, on winrt a streamreader can only get a io.stream..

The class im using above is a standard class that i have and use on all my wpf applications and it works good, only on winrt im having a big pain in the butthole with this..

Thank you.

Comment: First of all I think your path format (`ms-appx:///Data/cardsDB.xml`) would be something suspicious if it were my code (maybe the compiler somehow doesn't like having `"/"` instead of `"\"`). If I were you I would try to put it under `C:\test` (for example) and load it as `"C:\test\cardsDB.xml"`? Otherwise, we can't give you little help with the second error message (`Data at the root level is invalid`) if we are not able take a look at the insides of your xml file.

Comment: I will try changing from "/" to "\" and i will report back, about the inside of the xml file.. it is on my question on how it looks like, but i will copy it in here again: path = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><cards></cards>"

Comment: Changing from "/" to "\" did not work. i still get the same exceptions, thanks anyways for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the xml file's Properties, the Build Action should be Content.

Then, to open a content file you need to do something like this (sorry it's in C# as I don't know the VB syntax all that well):

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Data/cardsDB.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

*Note:* `OpenStreamForReadAsync` is an extension method for which you need to add `using System.IO;`. Also, the method in which you add this code must be async.

Now you just need to pass this `stream` variable to the XmlSerializer's `Deserialize` method.

Comment: I have tried the 'GetResourceStream' but it looks like it does not exist. i get this: 'GetResourceStream is not a member of Windows.UI.Xaml.Application'

Comment: @Rui I see. You should've made it clear that it's a WP 8.1 non-SL  app (XAML app or however these are called). I changed the code for that version of the framework. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for that, i really lost 2 days looking on the internet and couldn't find anything(well i was close once when i tried to use the storagefile). Yeah sorry if i was not clear..